# Display video in HTML using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, thymeleaf

Can anyone advise on how to add a video to a page using Thymleaf?

I have tried:

```
  <iframe th:src="@{/video/video.mp4}" width="100px" height="100px"></iframe>
```

And

```
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source th:src="@{/video/video.mp4}" type=video/mp4>
  </video>
```

And neither one is working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Not displaying on a web page

Comment: Have you checked the developer console? (Are you getting a 404 -- meaning your link is wrong?) (Can you visit your video directly in the browser -- do you have the correct URL?) (Have you viewed the page source in the browser -- is Thymeleaf running and parsing your `th:*` attributes?)

Comment: I am getting a 404, and I can't access the video from my browser, even though its in static/video/video.mp4, as are all other resources.

Comment: And how is the url you are using for your other static resources different from your video? (Can you view other static resources?)

Comment: I can. I moved the video to image folder and now it can be accessed. Thank you for your help!